# Python - order columns and compare rows in csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, if-statement

I've got a .csv file coming from a network capture. In this file there're repeated messages that I need to identify.

> Sender A, Receiver G, 43, Info...
>   Sender H, Receiver R, 43, Info...
>   Sender A, Receiver G, 27, Info...
>   Sender N, Receiver Z, 43, Info...
>   Sender A, Receiver G, 1367, Info...
>   Sender R, Receiver P, 43, Info...
>   Sender A, Receiver G, 43, Info...
>   Sender H, Receiver R, 111, Info...

The repeated parameter is the identifier, but that wouldn't necessarily mean that the message is repeated. In that case I would need to check also the Sender and the Receiver. I've thought about sorting the file by its 3rd column and then loop from top to down while comparing the value in those columns. 
  While I've managed to isolate the lines with repeated numbers in a file, my problems come here
  Firstly, I don't manage to order it properly
  Secondly, I don't know how to read and at the same time compare one column (or two in my case) with its value below. I think the idea would consist of an anidated if *(if row[2]==row[2, line below], then check if row[0] and row[1] are == to rows [0 and 1, line below])*, but after a long time thinking I don't manage to create anything decent that makes that comparison.

The idea would be printing or saving cases in which at the same time those 3 conditions (1st three columns basically) are repeated.

> Sender A, Receiver G, 43, Info...
>   Sender A, Receiver G, 43, Info...

Maybe I'm making it too complicated and there's an easier or quicker method. Anyway, I post my code and would appreciate if somebody helped. Greetings

```
entries = []
duplicated = []

with open('file.csv', 'rt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        if columns[2] not in entries:
            entries.append(columns[2])
        else:
            duplicated.append(columns[2]) 

#List with duplicated=null->no error
if duplicated==[]:
    print "\nNo duplicated\n"

#Other case, there might be duplicates
else:
    #Store error cases in New.csv
    with open('New.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        with open('file.csv', 'r') as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
                columns = line.strip().split(',')
                if columns[2] in duplicate_entries:
                    out_file.write(line)

#TO SORT THE EXCEL FILE. CURRENTLY NOT WORKING PROPERLY
##    data = csv.reader(open('Other.csv'),delimiter=',')
##    sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
##    with open('Other.csv', 'w') as out_file:
##        for item in sortedlist:
##            out_file.write(item)
```

Comment: What should happen if the identifier, sender and receiver match?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, either print repetitions (both rows), count repeated cases or write them into the file... for the moment I just want to identify them. 
Greetings!

Comment: Could you add few example rows and expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really any need to sort the file, but your sorting probably ran afoul of sorting strings vs. numbers; strings are sorted lexicographically, which means `'10'` is sorted *before* `'2'` because `1` comes earlier in the character set and the `0` does not come into play.

You can track repeats by storing them in a dictionary; this lets you look up previously seen matches. This is easiest with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

seen = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    for row in reader:
        key = (row[0], row[1], row[2])  # sender, receiver, id
        seen[key].append(row)

    with open('new.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        for collected in seen.values():
            if len(collected) > 1:
                writer.writerows(collected)
```

This version groups rows from the input CSV by the (sender, receiver, id) triplet, and then writes all rows out again, but only if there are more than one row per triplet.

You could also keep a count; count how often you see the triplets in a dictionary; a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would make that easy as well as offer sorting by frequency afterwards:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    counts = Counter((r[0], r[1], r[2]) for r in reader)

with open('new.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf)
    for (sender, receiver, id), count in counts.most_common():
        writer.writerow([sender, receiver, id, count])
```

Demo with your sample data:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sample = '''\
... Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
... Sender H,Receiver R,43,Info...
... Sender A,Receiver G,27,Info...
... Sender N,Receiver Z,43,Info...
... Sender A,Receiver G,1367,Info...
... Sender R,Receiver P,43,Info...
... Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
... Sender H,Receiver R,111,Info...
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> seen = defaultdict(list)
>>> reader = csv.reader(sample)
>>> for row in reader:
...     key = (row[0], row[1], row[2])  # sender, receiver, id
...     seen[key].append(row)
... 
>>> import sys
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> for collected in seen.values():
...     if len(collected) > 1:
...         writer.writerows(collected)
... 
Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
```

or the `Counter` approach:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> reader = csv.reader(sample)
>>> counts = Counter((r[0], r[1], r[2]) for r in reader)
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> for (sender, receiver, id), count in counts.most_common():
...     writer.writerow([sender, receiver, id, count])
... 
Sender A,Receiver G,43,2
Sender A,Receiver G,1367,1
Sender A,Receiver G,27,1
Sender N,Receiver Z,43,1
Sender H,Receiver R,111,1
Sender H,Receiver R,43,1
Sender R,Receiver P,43,1
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Well, the reason to sort the file is because I'd want to print/store repetition cases together... you answer seems very complete though, I'll try to implement it later and accept the answer as soon as I make it work on my code ^^. Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieters showed you very nice solutions in "pure" Python
and I show you something different - example with `pandas` module

(I use `StringIO` to simulate file reading)

```
data = """Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
Sender H,Receiver R,43,Info...
Sender A,Receiver G,27,Info...
Sender N,Receiver Z,43,Info...
Sender A,Receiver G,1367,Info...
Sender R,Receiver P,43,Info...
Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
Sender H,Receiver R,111,Info..."""

import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO 

# read all file
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=None, header=None)

print df

# group rows by values in columns 0, 1, 2
for name, group in df.groupby([0,1,2]):
    print '\n', '-'*40, '\n'
    print 'name:', name
    print 'len:', len(group)
    print
    print group

    if len(group) > 1:
        # append (`mode='a'`) data to `results.csv`
        group.to_csv('results.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
        #group.to_csv('results.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

I use `pd.read_csv()` to read all file.
(I assume there is no row with headers in file `header=None`
and I don't use any column as row indexer `index_col=None`)

Then I group rows by  values in columns 0, 1, 2 (and print them).
If any group has more then one element I append it to file `'results.csv'`.

I get file with

```
Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
```

or if I don't use `index=False` in `to_csv() I get also row number (index)

```
0,Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
6,Sender A,Receiver G,43,Info...
```

And this is what I print on screen

```
          0           1     2        3
0  Sender A  Receiver G    43  Info...
1  Sender H  Receiver R    43  Info...
2  Sender A  Receiver G    27  Info...
3  Sender N  Receiver Z    43  Info...
4  Sender A  Receiver G  1367  Info...
5  Sender R  Receiver P    43  Info...
6  Sender A  Receiver G    43  Info...
7  Sender H  Receiver R   111  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender A', 'Receiver G', 27)
len: 1

          0           1   2        3
2  Sender A  Receiver G  27  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender A', 'Receiver G', 43)
len: 2

          0           1   2        3
0  Sender A  Receiver G  43  Info...
6  Sender A  Receiver G  43  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender A', 'Receiver G', 1367)
len: 1

          0           1     2        3
4  Sender A  Receiver G  1367  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender H', 'Receiver R', 43)
len: 1

          0           1   2        3
1  Sender H  Receiver R  43  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender H', 'Receiver R', 111)
len: 1

          0           1    2        3
7  Sender H  Receiver R  111  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender N', 'Receiver Z', 43)
len: 1

          0           1   2        3
3  Sender N  Receiver Z  43  Info...

---------------------------------------- 

name: ('Sender R', 'Receiver P', 43)
len: 1

          0           1   2        3
5  Sender R  Receiver P  43  Info...
```

Comment: Hi! I'm relatively new to Python and I've never used Pandas, to be honest... in fact I doubt files I'll manage would be greater than 1k-2k lines and if it'd be worth to add Pandas just for this. I'll have to think about it for the future, for sure, and thanks for your answer!